# File path from "Media file access"

Tags: android, file, directory, uri, media

It is possible to recognize whether the file obtained using "Media file access" is stored on the SD card or in the Internal Memory ?   For example, is it possible to find out the information from a media URI? In my opinion, it is only possible to find out the name of a subdirectory, but then it is no longer possible to find out the name of parent subdirectory.

Thanks, Michal

```
 class Video {
        private final Uri uri;
        private final String name;
        private final int duration;
        private final int size;

        public Video(Uri uri, String name, int duration, int size) {
            this.uri = uri;
            this.name = name;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.size = size;
        }
    }
    List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
    };
    String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION +
            " >= ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
        String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    };
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    try (Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        selection,
        selectionArgs,
        sortOrder
    )) {
        // Cache column indices.
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int durationColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // Get values of columns for a given video.
            long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            int duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn);
            int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);

            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

            // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
            // that represents the media file.
            videoList.add(new Video(contentUri, name, duration, size));
        }
    }
```

it is possible to somehow find out that the video is on the SD card or in the memory.

Comment: Are you on Android Q? How exactly are you doing/getting your 'Media file access'?

Comment: Hi, Yes on Android Q or R .. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

Comment: I will not follow your link. Explain. Post minimal code. How did you obtain your media uri to begin with?

Comment: I wrote an example there

Comment: `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. Using that uri you will get files from both internal memory and removable sd card. But there are different uries for them. So if you use the one for the removeble card you know. You have to determine which storage volume they are on first. Then obtain that uri. As im laying under a palm tree right now i have no code at hand.

Comment: Im not completely shure if that works for the .Video. uri though. Otherwise use the .Files. uri.

Comment: I think it will return a pile of files, their name, their size and their URI, but how to know if this URI is on the SD card or if it is on the Internal memory .. I don't think it's possible .. or how to just list files from the Internal memory and files on SD card skipped

Comment: No. You make two querys. One for internal memory and one for removable sd card. You use two different uries. That is what i said. So you know exactly where every file resides.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean by two queries, one for files on the Internal Memory and the other on the files on the SD card. Unfortunately, I didn't figure out how to do this, because the only thing that can be changed is EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and give INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI instead.   Unfortunately, this means internal from the memory space of my application. And External in my opinion means everything except my app, ie Internal memory + SD card.

Comment: I dont have my code at hand at the moment and hope to help you later. Did you read all the threads tagged mediastore?

Comment: content://media/external/video/media, content://media/external_primary/video/media and content://media/0146-2a3b/video/media. Replace volume id with that of your sd card. The first one gives all.